# Poner texto sobre un borde

Tags: html, css

Sé como poner un borde a un texto, pero ahora quiero hacer lo contrario, a un div que contiene un borde agregarle un texto que interrumpe el borde.
[image: el texto que dice "Iniciar Sesión" es lo que quiero hacer]

Comment: Hola Jonathan, ¿qué has intentado hasta el momento? Sería ideal si pudieras añadir tu código HTML y CSS para que podamos ver qué problema concreto estás encontrando. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: La respuesta de cooper es la adecuada para lo que buscas, ya que sigue la semántica de HTML, algo muy importante, pero que muchas veces no lo tenemos en cuenta he intentamos resolver todo a base de DIVs y clases, cuando quizás en HTML5 hay un elemento que nos permite hacerlo. Quería darle un punto a cooper, pero el sistema no me deja.

Comment: En mi opinion ambas respuestas estan tecnicamente correctas, aunque como comentaron ya, la respuesta de cooper seria la mas adecuada semanticamente (despues de todo es lo importante de html5) Por cierto, por defecto esta etiqueta trae su estilo css, capaz sea importante aclarar este valor default que incluye:
display: block; Espero hayas podido solucionar tu problema!

Answer (score 12):

Existen 2 formas de resolver esto:

- **Solución 1:** Crear un div y sobre el div posicionar el texto con un fondo blanco para justamente lograr ese efecto de "interrupción" del borde. Sería algo asi:

```css
div{
    margin-top:20px;
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    border:2px solid black;
}

h1{
    width: 50px;
    font-size:18px;
    margin-top:-12px;
    margin-left:7px;
    background:white;
}
```

```html
<div>

    <h1>Titulo</h1>

</div>
```

Con la propiedad `width` le das el ancho del fondo al texto. El `margin-top` en negativo logra que el texto quede superpuesto al borde del div.

- **Solución 2:** utilizar las etiquetas `fieldset` y `legend`.

```html
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Titulo</legend>
 </fieldset>
```

Vos elegís.

Answer (score 6):

Lo que buscas se conoce como "fieldset". Es un elemento concreto de html. Y el texto que quieres mostrar es un tag concreto llamado "legend".

Te pongo aquí el ejemplo:

```html
<fieldset>
<legend>Tu texto</legend>
<div>Aquí puedes ir rellenandolo con lo que quieras mostrar dentro del fieldset</div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal como dicen en anteriores respuestas, la etiqueta **legend** que escribes dentro del cuadro creado mediante **fieldset** te permite escribir un texto en el borde.

Comment: Hola Bernat y bienvenido, lo invito a que de un recorrido por el sitio para saber [¿Cómo responder correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answering)